# Jenkins pipeline parallel step with dynamically built list

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that has some weird behavior and I'm not sure what's going on.

```
node(){

  myFuncs = [:]
  String[] myFuncsToCall = ["one", "two"]

  for (int i = 0; i < myFuncsToCall.size(); i++) {
    func = myFuncsToCall[$i]
    myFuncs[func] = {
      "${func}"()
    }
  }

  parallel myFuncs
}

def one(){
  echo "one"
}

def two(){
  echo "two"
}
```

It's interesting, because the job output shows parallel branching for both 'one' and 'two', but only calls method 'two' for both parallel branches.

I imagine there's something groovy related that I'm missing here, but am hoping it's possible to dynamically call method names like this so I can have large sets of dynamic inputs to jobs that need to run with variable inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

func is not a local variable but a dynamically defined property on the main script. If no type or the keyworkd `def` specified to the left from the var name then groovy will try to resolve it and Jenkins configures the main script in such a way that func will be assinged to the main script as a new property. Basically, it creates a global var since there is only one instance of the main script (Jenkinsfile itself).
Therefore, this global var gets changed in the loop and stores the last result only ("two"). When it comes to running the closures every closure the value from the global var. Hence, "two".
To change this behaviour simple add def or explicit type to make func a local variable.

```
node(){

  def myFuncs = [:]
  String[] myFuncsToCall = ["one", "two"]

  for (int i = 0; i < myFuncsToCall.size(); i++) {
    def func = myFuncsToCall[i]
    myFuncs[func] = {
      "${func}"()
    }
  }

  parallel myFuncs
}

def one(){
  echo "one"
}

def two(){
  echo "two"
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation of the issue and is exactly what I did to resolve it once I realized that the vars were treated as global scope. Very weird / unexpected.